# ipf filter on solaris 11 crashes

Tags: firewall, solaris

First I run:

```
sudo netservices limited
```

then

```
sudo ipf -D disable
sudo ipf -E enable
sudo ipf -f /home/aubrey/ipf.conf
sudo ipfstat -io
```

I also disabled `ssh` in system services

After a few hours I run

```
sudo ipfstat -io
```

and I discover the firewall has reset (open in/ open out).

Also the network connection drops its DHCP IPv4 address to `0.0.0.0`

I'm guessing it has to do with `netservices` limited which increases security, but why does network connection drop and why does the firewall reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think I managed to fix the problem. The logfile showed that the dchpagent was trying to renew its lease. Unfortunately the firewall was not configured correctly and would block dhcpagent from renewing. The connection would become invalid according to the invalid lease. So adding the correct rule in the firewall seems to have fixed the problem.

Kind Regards
Aubrey.

Answer (score 2):

The version of ipf bundled with Solaris 11 is 4.1.9, which is old. To my very great consternation the official page at ANU has gone offline; does anyone what's happened?

I don't know whether Oracle has been working on it themselves but Sun added it to opensolaris many years ago and it transferred across to S11, or at least that's how I remember it.

Why not try building 4.1.32 or 33 from source (here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ipfilter/files/ipfilter/) I couldn't get 5.x to build on solaris and it doesn't look like any work has been done on it for a long time. I was using GCC, you may get better mileage with sun studio, now free as well.

I built my own because GRE support was broken in the last official version I tried and I need it for PPTP. Other than that been using it for years (since v3.x) with no issues.

Also I don't know about using it with DHCP, kinda cuts across the way the config files work. You may do better making system addresses static. I've never tried it with DHCP myself, and frankly can't see why you'd try.